# What Hadoop jar dependencies do I need to setup a HDFS sink in Flume?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I'm using a Docker image of Flume from probablyfine/flume.

I'm trying to configure a HDFS sink and I'm getting this error about dependencies. Google search results show I need to include Hadoop libs, but many of the results are old from when Hadoop 1.0 had a single *hadoop-core-1.0.jar* that I could include in my Docker image.

I'm trying to include the jars straight from the Hadoop 2.9 bin download in */share/hadoop/common/*. But including these jars in my FLUME_CLASSPATH is not working.

```
FLUME_CLASSPATH=/var/tmp/hadoop/common/
```

I've also tried one level up and just doing the /hadoop/ directory. But it's all the same error before:

```
2018-01-22 21:49:21,643 (conf-file-poller-0) [ERROR 
- org.apache.flume.node.Poll
ingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingProperties
FileConfigurationProvider.java:146)] Failed to start agent because dependencies
were not found in classpath. Error follows.
java.lanat org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.configure(HDFSEventSink.java
:235)
        at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSinks(Abstrac
tConfiguat org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(
Abstractat org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$File
WatcherRat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)va:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:624)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
Caused bat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)o.SequenceFile$C
ompressiat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        ... 12 moreg.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Which specific jar dependency files do I need in my Docker image to setup a HDFS sink?

Comment: Try a different image https://hub.docker.com/r/avastsoftware/flume-hdfs/